# What Feed Reader libraries for Java are best?

Tags: java, rss, feed

What Java library would you say is the best for consuming and parsing feeds? Requirements:

- Embeddable
- Supports Atom & RSS
- Has caching architecture
- Should be able to deal with any feed format the same way

(Please: *one* suggestion per answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will [ROME](https://rome.dev.java.net/) do?

Comment: I like ROME, although it's not without its flaws - no caching architecture so you'll have to do that yourself, and you can sometimes get problems trying to read RSS and Atom in the same way due to the inherent nature of allowing multiple content fields in Atom.

Comment: It seems that FeedParser doesn't support ATOM 1.0, plus it's a dormant project. ROME on the other hand is still in active development.

Answer (score 0):

We also use ROME. While the SAX/eventing based [FeedParser](http://commons.apache.org/dormant/feedparser/) architecture is interesting it is a `dormant` project at Apache. 
The "dormant" at Apache seems to imply NO binary download links and NO active development.